# OSPF increase bandwidth with load-balancing

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, ospf, load-balancing

This is my current setup where i have `40Gbps` links between all 4 switches running `OSPF` using L3 links between them but now i want to double my bandwidth between switches so i am planning to add (dotted links) L3 links and let OSPF load-balance traffic on them, Do you think is there any issue to doing that or this is going to be just fine? ( want second set of eyes )

[image]

This is what my ospf config looks on all 4 switches.

```
interface Ethernet2/10
  no switchport
  mtu 9216
  ip address 192.168.250.9/30
  no ip ospf passive-interface
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
  no shutdown

interface Ethernet2/11
  no switchport
  mtu 9216
  ip address 192.168.250.13/30
  no ip ospf passive-interface
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
  no shutdown
```

## More details about current traffic flow

my current traffic flow looks like following diagram at present `SW` is active BGP switch so all in/out traffic from coming from ISP. then SW1 do load-sharing between two SW3/4 using OSPF ECMP. Last 1 years we have no single complain about voice issue or quality issue ( everyone is happy ). Now when my SW1 is failed then OSPF move BGP route to SW2 and make it `active` and traffic start flowing from SW2 to SW3/4  ( I have tested this multiple time by manually shifting BGP )

[image]

## Update - 2

Load-sharing info for OSPF/ECMP

I have following load-sharing configured which is default on cisco nexus switches.

```
# show ip load-sharing
IPv4/IPv6 ECMP load sharing:
Universal-id (Random Seed): 2223335843
Load-share mode : address source-destination port source-destination
GRE-Outer hash is disabled.
Concatenation is disabled.
```

Comment: Be sure you upgrade the links between SW1-2 and SW 3-4

Comment: Oh yes.. forgot to add that in diagram. good catch!  but otherwise do you see any issue to just bring up L3 Link and handover to OSFP ?

Comment: As I recall, you do a lot with VoIP. You could end up with a lot of out-of-order packets that would absolutely kill VoIP.

Comment: @RonMaupin I would argue that CEF/ECMP handles "flows" pretty well and will prevent out-of-order delivery of VoIP streams nicely, by assigning a given flow to the same egress interface consistently.

Comment: @Marc'netztier'Luethi, that really depends. Routing protocol per-packet load balancing can really mess up real-time protocols. I was actually thinking of your layer-3 channel suggestion because that will certainly provide per-flow balancing.

Comment: @RonMaupin agreed, if blunt "per packet load balancing" is happening, things will go downhill from there with VoIP. I'll go and look for that document explaining how CEF/ECMP will handle flows on a N9K.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I have updated my question `Update-2` section with load-sharing info, and look like it use source-destination port for load balancing so it's kind of flow based load-sharing. In that case it will keep audio packet stream on single link and will not do `per-Packet` load sharing... am i missing anything here?

Comment: If you have configured that, it should be OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As these are Point-to-Point links, I would consider using the outage to configure each /30 interface with `ip ospf network point-to-point`.  (New and existing links).  This reduces the hello and dead timers.  This configuration also reduces the need to negotiate a DR and BDR.

Lastly, I would verify the OSPF neighbor states and routing tables, before and after the cutover.  You should see ECMP routes after the cutovers and the appropriate neighborships.

Comment: getting downtime would be fire drill for us, because we have many many customers so that path would be not easy. but is it possible on `SW2` and `SW3/4` switches i configured `ip ospf network point-to-point` and then failover my traffic to SW2 and do same on SW1 and SW3/4? I have updated my question

Comment: The plan appears sound to me.  Just be cautious that traffic is still flowing as expected in the failover state.

Comment: Also I’m planning to add high ospf cost on new link and wait for sometime until all settle down then reduce cost to start ECMP traffic

Comment: Do you think if i change one of idle link of OSPF to `p2p` will disturb my current traffic flow?\

Comment: No, however I would still CYA.  Maintenance window, check preferred routes, look at Netflow, review interface counters and etc.

Comment: Finally i have upgraded my OSPF bandwidth as per i described with zero downtime, add additional L3 links with /30 subnet and configured them with `point-to-point`, first i have convert idle links to `p2p` and then shift my traffic to those links and then convert other links to `p2p`. everything works great so far without issue. OSFP is king :)  Thanks you for help.

Answer (score 8):

There's two ways to do that.

- your proposed way, by adding a second link with its own /30 or /31, 
  making sure that OSPF installs multiple *equal cost* routes in the
  routing table, and let CEF's ECMP (EqualCostMultiPath) forwarding handle the
  packet pushing and the distribution of flows across the set
  of available links. CEF/ECMP uses a different load sharing logic than Port-Channel, and can handle uneven numbers of links a lot better than Port-Channels do. See [Ivan Pepelniak's Blog post](https://blog.ipspace.net/2006/10/cef-load-sharing-details.html) for reference.
- use L3 Port-Channels: Move the IP and routing configuration to a port-channel object (which does *not* have the "switchport" command), and join the given interfaces to that object. Let Port-Channel load distribution logic handle the distribution of flows.

Your proposed idea is more L3/routing oriented, but scaling it might have some issues: You will use a lot of /30 or /31s. You can scale in odd numbers, but you'll have to configure a new link and possibly subnet for every scaling step (or go `ip unnumbered`). On the upside, individual links with their own subnet are easier to troubleshoot - pinging across a given single link "comes naturally".

On the other hand, L3 Port-Channels don't need more IP subnets and don't actually touch your given routing configuration logic. Port-Channel is a bit more "Nexus style", as the whole history of Nexus switches is based on the VPC concept (which does not quite apply here, I'll admit). Scaling of additional links is easier - just add two more, without touching any IP or routing configuration. However, rules for Port-Channels apply (e.g. keep number of links in powers of 2), while troubleshooting individual links of a Port-Channel is less straightforward (can't ping across an individual link without removing it from the port-channel and reconfiguring it)

ADDON-1: And oh yes, by all means DO follow TDurden's advice to configure point-to-point on the ... ehm.. point-to-point links (really bad pun, I'll admit)

CAVEAT-1: When using port-channels ensure that you select a load-balancing strategy that fits the expected communication patterns for the given link. When connecting  a router to a router (essentially only two MAC addresses on the link), then "Src/Dst MAC" might not have the desired results... For reference, see the [Cisco Nexus 9000 Series NX-OS Interfaces Configuration Guide, Release 9.2(x)](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/92x/interfaces/configuration/guide/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x/b-cisco-nexus-9000-nx-os-interfaces-configuration-guide-92x_chapter_0111.html#concept_D1EAFA3071194B5B829D17368AFC27A6)

ADDON-2:
On Nexus 9000, with ECMP/CEF, the load-sharing algorithm can be configured to include L4 properties: `ip load-sharing address source-destination port source-destination` See [Configuring Load-Sharing in the Unicast FIB](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/92x/unicast/configuration/guide/b-cisco-nexus-9000-series-nx-os-unicast-routing-configuration-guide-92x/b-cisco-nexus-9000-series-nx-os-unicast-routing-configuration-guide-92x_chapter_01111.html#task_19C4B4F175DF4316AA52A3B94AF6EB8E) from the Unicast Routing configuration gude.

CAVEAT-2 When using L3-Port-Channels, keep an eye on the "bandwidth" property of the port-channel interface when a member link goes down. Depending on hardware/software platform, the bandwidth of the port-channel interface might get reduced accordingly, and OSPF might react to that by increasing the given link's cost. This might have (un)intended consequences for the topology.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, I have updated my question with more details, currently SW1 is active and that one is doing load-sharing, now if i add one more link between SW1 to SW3/4 why do you think ECMP will be  issue? my current ECMP setup running fine last 1 year without any single issue. I am not worried about wasting IP or typing config. I am trying make it less painful without downtime :(

Comment: ECMP doesn't support Per-Packet load-sharing, it used Flow based load-sharing. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/mp_l3_vpns/configuration/xe-3s/asr903/mp-l3-vpns-xe-3s-asr903-book/mp-l3-vpns-xe-3s-asr903-book_chapter_0100.pdf